# How to execute code after response has been sent?

Tags: grails

I have a need in which i want to execute some code after the rendering process has been finished. I tried the afterView filter but this does not take into account the use of layouts.

How can i execute some code after the view has been rendered? (example programmatical logout code)

Comment: Are you sure that `afterView` is executed after rendering view but before applying this data into layout?

Comment: Yep.. according to the docs 'afterView - Executed after view rendering. Takes an Exception as an argument which will be non-null if an exception occurs during processing. Note: this Closure is called before the layout is applied.'

Comment: why do you want to logout after rendering the page ? why not before?

Comment: The page is requested by an external process which we need to feed with some data. We let the external process login with a 'virtual' user and after rendering the response, we would like to logout the 'virtual' user.

Comment: Hm, at this case I can suggest you to use Spring Security plugins. It authenticates user for current request only, and can be easily extended with 'virtual user authentication'

Answer (score 1):

You can still use standard Java EE filter: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html
and put it into grails by using webxml plugin: http://www.grails.org/plugin/webxml

Answer (score 0):

On the rendered view, add an onload hook to post an ajax call to your logout controller/action.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what need is [afterInterceptor](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Controllers/afterInterceptor.html). This is called after you have executed render statement from your controller action.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That has the same issue as a Filter since it's the same thing. It runs before SiteMesh